# Whats the difference between the Matches() and IsExactly() in FHIR.NET API

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm using the Fhir.NET API from here: https://fire.ly/fhir-api/

I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between using the `Matches()` method between two `IDeepComparable` instances versus using `IsExactly()` between two `IDeepComparable` instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matches()` will result `true` when the left operand will match the right pattern operand. For example a `Coding` resource has several properties, like `System`, `Code` and `Display`.

When the right operand only has values for `System` and `Code` then it will match a left operand with the same `System` and `Code` value and also a `Display` value.

The following unittest will make it clearer:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void CodeableConceptMatching()
        {
            var c1 = new Coding("http://example.com/system", "code1");
            var c2 = new Coding("http://example.com/system", "code1", "Display Text");

            Assert.IsTrue(c2.Matches(c1));
            Assert.IsFalse(c1.Matches(c2));
            Assert.IsFalse(c2.IsExactly(c1));
            Assert.IsFalse(c1.IsExactly(c2));
        }
```

Comment: Ahh...I think I see why it wasn't working for me.  I was thinking that it would make more sense to match the other way.  c1 does match c2 in that c2 contains everything in c1 (but with extra stuff).  I'm comparing two patients where the source patient (c1) only has a subset of data related to the full patient (c2) for updating (think PATCH).  Once I map everything from c1 to c2 (which includes value conflict resolution where I may not necessarily take the value from c1) I want to know if everything from c1 made it to c2.  I guess I'll have to hand-code this type of matching.

Comment: I think of it like a string match.  If c1 = "Ed" and c2 = "Edward".  c1 matches c2, but c2 does not match c1 yet that is how matching seems to work in the API. You could probably make arguments for both ways.